# Error - No Data in Table (using JavaScript Fetch)

Tags: javascript

I am using Fetch API to get jsonified data from Flask app to show in Bootstrap5 table. I am also using Bootstrap5 code to initialize the table.

When I open the page, I see response [image: HTML Page]

Why am seeing "No data available in Table" in response?

I tried this:

```html
<table id="dataTable"  class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>

<script>
  const table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  fetch('employees')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(employee => {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `
          <td>${employee.id}</td>
          <td>${employee.name}</td>
        `;
        table.appendChild(row);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the element with the "No data available" before adding new elements to the table.

Assuming that the "No data available" is an tr you can do like this

```
<script>
  const table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  var noDataElement = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
  noDataElement.remove();

  fetch('employees')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(employee => {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `
          <td>${employee.id}</td>
          <td>${employee.name}</td>
        `;
        table.appendChild(row);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: may not be an optimal solution because leaving everything else in my HTML as such, just including the code you added, it is showing me no table headers and also taking away all Bootstrap5 formatting.

Comment: It also seems that the following table initialization code is causing this error to happen. If I get rid of this how can I still initialize my table? -   $(document).ready(function () {
$('#dataTable').DataTable();
});

Comment: @SameerDhar You need to put all relevant code in your question, ideally before people take the time to answer it. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score -2):

This code works perfectly:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
$('#dataTable').DataTable()
  const table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  var noDataElement = table.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
  noDataElement.remove();
  fetch('employees')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(employee => {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `
          <td>${employee.id}</td>
          <td>${employee.name}</td>
        `;
        table.appendChild(row);
      });
    })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: An explanation of the code and what it does is always better than a code dump of changes. Also, this adds the jQuery DataTables plugin, but the question does not have the [jquery] tag; adding libraries unnecessarily is considered bad form.